# How to build/run specific subprojects of elasticsearch source code

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to rebuild only the file or sub-projects which i modify.So that i need not build the whole project again.
Also every time i make a change in file,i had to restart my windows to delete .lock file,there has to be some way to handle this.